# What it is the duration of stored variables in the session using express js?

Tags: node.js, express, session, session-variables, express-session

For example `req.session.email = mamam@ymamam.com` i want to know for how long this variable will be available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what values you have configured while creating that session.

```
app.use(session({
  cookieName: 'session',
  duration: 30 * 60 * 1000,
  activeDuration: 5 * 60 * 1000,
}));
```

By Default your session variables will last till your Node get's restarted.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the `store` you use - assuming you haven't configured a store then by default `express-session` uses an in-memory one, meaning your property will be available until your Node process is restarted.

FWIW the `MemoryStore` isn't designed for use in production applications, you should use a more robust store - see [compatible stores](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session#compatible-session-stores).